# How do we achieve dependency injection in Heldion SE?

Tags: helidon

The `@Inject` annotation works fine in Helidon MP application. However, I can't find `@Inject` for Helidon SE. How do we achieve dependency injection in SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helidon SE's philosophy is to give you full control of everything ("no magic"), so it does not intrinsically support dependency injection (this is a deliberate choice and a deliberate tradeoff).  If you prefer the dependency injection style of programming, I recommend you use Helidon MP, which is, as a [MicroProfile](https://microprofile.io/) implementation, explicitly designed for it.